# Primefaces calendar popup not working with Google maps (full screen only)

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-gmap

The Primefaces Calendar component seems not to work properly within a Google maps Infowindow, (ONLY when the map is full screen).
When the calendar button is clicked, the popup is not shown. I initially thought it could be just the component 'z-index' css property or the 'display',  but after many tries couldn't fix it.
This is working fine if the Map is not in Full screen mode.

I would appreciate if someones knows a workaround for this. Due to limited space in the Infowindow, cannot use the Inline calendar.

The picture below shows the popup.
I'm using Primefaces 7.0

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Most likely the cause is somewhat related to the z-index. Can you see if using `p:datePicker`(https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/datepicker?id=datepicker,  the successor of `p:calendar` and using its `appendTo` attribute can help you getting it shown? I susspect the 'popup' part is added to a piece of html that is masked by the map and which you cannot solve by using the z-index

Comment: Yes indeed using the p:datePicker it works! Many thanks Kukeltje you really made my day :)